# How to make an extension add a custom component?

Tags: typescript, cocoscreator

I have a `TypeScript` file with a class that inherits `cc.Component`. I want to put it inside an extension package and have it accessible in the editor (have an option to add it to a node etc.) once the package is added. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to the `package.json`:

```
"runtime-resource": {
    "path": "scripts",
    "name": "scripts"
}
```

Afterwards put your `.ts` file inside `scripts` folder in the package directory. Things should more or less look something like this as the result:

[image]

Source: https://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/how-to-make-an-extension-add-a-custom-component/51004/6?u=quickz